# Initializing In Try/Catch

Tags: java, android

I have run into quite a snag while writing my app. Here is my issue:

I am trying to initialize the file input stream like so:

```
FileInputStream fis
fis = openFileInput(selectedFile);
```

Then put this 1 line later:

```
byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
```

Problem is both bits of code need try/catch statements and the second block cannot recognize fis because it was initialized within a try/catch. Here is my code:

```
private void openFile(String selectedFile) {
        String value = "";
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(selectedFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What should I do? (Thanks in advance)

Comment: initialize fis to a temporary value (will it work if you try `null`). The thing is, that's how the program should work.

Comment: Declare the variables outside the try/catch, or catch both exceptions.

Comment: You try and open the file, and if it fails you only print the stack trace and try and go on... Which will yield an NPE. Make your `openFile()` method throw `IOException` at the very least!

Comment: FYI - `FileNotFoundException` is an `IOException` so you can just catch both in one `catch(IOException e)` statement. And don't forget to close your IO streams in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in this situation is not to catch IOException at all.

```
private void openFile(String selectedFile) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis =  openFileInput(selectedFile);
        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
```

It does not make sense to continue after you got FileNotFoundException

Comment: don't forget that you need to close your input stream on the finally block though, so even this should be surrounded by a `try/finally`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `FileInputStream fis = null;` when you first declare the variable.

You could also run your code like this because IOException will also catch the file not found exception.

```
String value = "";
FileInputStream fis;
try {
  fis = openFileInput(selectedFile);
  byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You'll also either want to return after the first exception, or add a null check in the second block.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will mark your answer as correct but I need 12 more minutes

Comment: I made a little edit that gives you another way to fix up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the FileInputStream to a temporary value. `null` would be the best option, as in:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
```

The reason for this is because if your try statement throws an error, then the fis will never me initialized. Then you'll have problems. If you don't exit the thing entirely, you should also add the statement after the try/catch blocks that tests if the value is null, just so that the program does not throw a null pointer exception.

So maybe something like:

```
if(fis == null) {
    return; // Which will just end the method.
}
```

Also might want to put the try/catches together (you should still declare the other stuff outside of the try, at least anything you plan on using directly later on in the code) but it just might be more efficient coding wise), as in:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
byte[] input = null;
try {
    fis = openFileInput(selectedFile);
    input = new byte[fis.available()];
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```